# How to prevent going back in React Native using React Navigation and 'beforeRemove' eventListener with custom modal?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v6

What I want to achieve is straightforward. I want the user to be forced to confirm exiting a tab navigator called 'checkout'.

I read on React Navigation docs about [preventing going back](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/) about the 'beforeRemove' event which seems neat and the right thing to use.

The problem is that in their example they call Alert in the eventlistener whereas I want to show a custom modal with a yes and no button.

This is React Navigations example code:

```
function EditText({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState('');
  const hasUnsavedChanges = Boolean(text);

  React.useEffect(
    () =>
      navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
        if (!hasUnsavedChanges) {
          // If we don't have unsaved changes, then we don't need to do anything
          return;
        }

        // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prompt the user before leaving the screen
        Alert.alert(
          'Discard changes?',
          'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
          [
            { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
            {
              text: 'Discard',
              style: 'destructive',
              // If the user confirmed, then we dispatch the action we blocked earlier
              // This will continue the action that had triggered the removal of the screen
              onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
            },
          ]
        );
      }),
    [navigation, hasUnsavedChanges]
  );

  return (
    <TextInput
      value={text}
      placeholder="Type something…"
      onChangeText={setText}
    />
  );
}
```

This is the code I have tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {
      if (userConfirmedExit) {
        navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
      } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowExitModal(true);
      }
    });
  }, [navigation, userConfirmedExit]);

  const handleConfirmExit = () => {
    setUserConfirmedExit(true);
    navigation.replace('ProfileTab');
  };

  const handleDeclineExit = () => setShowExitModal(false);
```

I am bound to use the navigation.dispatch(e.data.action) inside the eventListener but the handleConfirmExit function must live outside of it and I just can't figure out how to use the beforeRemove listener AND showing a custom modal from where I can exit the tab.

The listener is firing when pressing the back button and the modal shows but nothing happens when pressing yes (i.e running the handleConfirmExit function).

I have tried removing dependencies from the useEffect. The one thing that did work, but only on Android was this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setShowExitModal(true);
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const handleConfirmExit = () => {
    navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove', () => {});
    navigation.replace('ProfileTab');
  };

  const handleDeclineExit = () => setShowExitModal(false);
```

On iOS the modal stays onto the next screen for some reason and the culprit I think is the bad implementation of 'beforeRemove' listener in the last example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did and it works fine, but I am sure there is a better solution out there.

```
const [showExitModal, setShowExitModal] = useState(false);
let exitEvent = useRef<
    EventArg<
      'beforeRemove',
      true,
      {
        action: Readonly<{
          type: string;
          payload?: object | undefined;
          source?: string | undefined;
          target?: string | undefined;
        }>;
      }
    >
  >();
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      exitEvent.current = e;  
      setShowExitModal(true);    
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  const handleConfirmExit = () => {
    if (exitEvent.current) {
      navigation.dispatch(exitEvent.current.data.action);
    }
  };
```

In the markup:

```
 {showExitModal && (
        <CheckOutExitModal
          onYesPress={handleConfirmExit}
        />
      )}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a simple solution

```
 navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      
        if (e.data.action.type !="GO_BACK") {
           //"GO_BACK" is emitted by hardware button

          navigation.dispatch(e.data.action);
        } else {
    //your code to prevent hardware back button goes here } // 

} )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What I want to achieve is to be able to wait for the user response on the <CheckoutExitModal />, THEN do navigation.dispatch(e.data.action), IF the user pressed yes on the exit modal. The exitModal is shown on hardware back press OR if the user presses a custom back button in the header. I didn't know you could call .type like you've done in your answer (thanks for pointing it out), but can you please expand you answer to achieve what I described. You can perhaps look at my accepted answer for clarification of what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

use BackHandler , you can use navigation.goBack() instead of BackHandler.exitApp()

```
import { BackHandler} from "react-native";
const backAction = () => {
  Alert.alert("Discard changes?", "Are you sure you want to exit?", [
    {
      text: "NO",
      onPress: () => null,
      style: "cancel"
    },
    { text: "YES", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
  ]);
  return true;
};

useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
return () => {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
}   
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, I want the eventListener to fire when pressing a back button in the header as well, not only when pressing hardware back button. Also, I want to display a modal instead of an alert box. I got {showExitModal && <CheckOutExitModal/>} in the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the e.data.action in a state and then use this action by calling navigation.dispath(navigationAction) like below;

```
const [navigationState, setNavigationState] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {

const subscribe = navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {

 e.preventDefault();
        setExitModal(true)
        setNavigationAction(e.data.action)

}
},[])
```

and then call the navigation dispatch action

Comment: Thank you @Owais, this is essentially what I did in the end. I only used a ref instead of a state to store action. See accepted answer for further reference.